# WYSIWYG web page editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i want to use WYSIWYG web editor (the editor should have a option for adding videos, images,powerpoint etc..) on to my Rails application. Can any one suggest how can i integrate this editor into my rails application with above feature support. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Now it is known as CKeditor.

Please check [this](http://blog.caronsoftware.com/2006/08/07/fckeditor-plugin-for-rails) tutorial whcih explains how to integrate FCKEditor in Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [WYSI-dangerous: Why WYSIWYG editors are bad for your website](http://redcloth.org/articles/wysi-dangerous-why-wysiwyg-editors-are-bad-for-your-website/) and take a look at [wymeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/).